# Update TableB.attr when TableA.attr is updated MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I've been searching this in a while but I don't find exactly what I'm searching.

Here's the thing, I got two tables, let's call them tables A and B.
I need to update an attribute in B when A is updated. e.g: A.email and B.email. I need to automatically update B.email when the user updates his email in A.email.

I'm using MySQL phpmyadmin. I don't wanna mess with PHP code. I need this to be an automatic query everytime the user feels like updating his email.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Triggers, though your lack of Normalization might be a larger issue.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html